# Programmatically changing aspx button Click event on the Form Page_Load inconsistency

Tags: asp.net, button, click, eventhandler

I'm getting an inconsistent behavior. I need to change the User Control's button Click event. I have two buttons, all the changes I make to the controls work fine, but there is only one Click event that doesn't change :

```
((Button)EntryControl.FindControl("CancelConfirmation").FindControl("btnYesCancel")).Click += new EventHandler(btnYesCancelTrade_Click);
```

all the other changes work just fine:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Label)EntryControl.FindControl("lbPurchaseDate")).Visible = false;
        ((TextBox)EntryControl.FindControl("txPurchaseDate")).Visible = false;
        ((Label)EntryControl.FindControl("lbPurchasePrice")).Visible = false;
        ((TextBox)EntryControl.FindControl("txPurchasePrice")).Visible = false;

        ((Button)EntryControl.FindControl("CancelConfirmation").FindControl("btnNoCancel")).Click += new EventHandler(btnNoCancelTrade_Click);
        /*does not work*/ ((Button)EntryControl.FindControl("CancelConfirmation").FindControl("btnYesCancel")).Click += new EventHandler(btnYesCancelTrade_Click);
        ((Button)EntryControl.FindControl("CancelConfirmation").FindControl("btnYesCancel")).Text = "Yes Test";
    }
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Is this a dynamically added button? Or is it part of the markup (aspx.cs)?

Comment: The control is setup through markup. I'm reusing the control in a different area of the application and I need to use a different handler, so in the the webform page_load I'm making the changes, the estrange thing is, the other button which worked fine after I change it, is setup the same way to the button do isn't taking the Click handler change, even though the change in the Text does take place.

Comment: Never mind, I had to deregister the original handler before registering the new one. So I created a couple methods in the control so the web form can do this:

Comment: public void deregisterBtnYesCancel_Click()
        {
            btnYesCancel.Click -= btnYesCancel_Click;
        }

        public void deregisterBtnNoCancel_Click()
        {
            btnNoCancel.Click -= btnNoCancel_Click;
        }

Answer (score 0):

I was missing that I had to deregister the original handlers.